# Conditional Rendering Rule Order

Tags: personalization, rules-engine

Does anyone know how to change the order of the conditional rendering rules when you try to personalize a component?  I've added a custom rule that I'd like to show up at the top of the list, but it's buried somewhere in the middle, because it seems to be purely alphabetical.  I see that the "Predefined Rules" are always at the top, which tells me that this must be possible, I'm just doing it wrong.

So far I have tried the following, to no avail:

- moving my custom tags to the top of the Conditional Rendering's default multiselect
- changing the sort order of my custom tags
- changing the sort order of my custom element

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

Dug in a little after I saw your question and it appears that the `Predefined Rules` are handled as a special case;

Within `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Rules.RulesEditor.RulesEditorPage` and in the `GetGroupedElements` method there is an `OrderBy` involving a static ID `RulesEditorPage.PredefinedRulesItemId`.  After trying to follow the decompiled logic, my assumption is that the `Predefined Rules` are weighted at the top and then the order by falls back to `Element Folder` name. If that is the case, prefixing your `Element Folder` name with an underscore or adding your rules to the `Predefined Rules` `Element Folder` would likely get them visible toward the top (though neither one of those seems like a perfect solution).

*Further note:* if you are interested in digging in more, there are 3 processors that get executed out of box during the `RulesEditorPage` (in Sitecore 9.0.1 at least):

```
<getRenderedRuleElements>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.Rules.Taxonomy.GetContextFolder, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.Rules.Taxonomy.GetTags, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.Rules.Taxonomy.GetElementFolders, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
</getRenderedRuleElements>
```

These pipelines effectively find and aggregate the rules for a given `Tags Definition` under the `Rules Context Folder` (the multi-list that is sortable and relates your rules to let's say the `Insert Options` rule).  The result of this `getRenderedRuleElements` pipeline is what gets passed into the `RulesEditorPage` and eventually ordered and rendered when you click `Edit Rule`.  I will update my answer if I find anything else while I continue to dig.

Hope this helps.